# Is erase() in std::vector linear time operation?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

Page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/ says

> Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions) plus the number
>   of elements after the last element deleted (moving).

So, if I am deleting an element, say, with index `j` from vector of some length `n` (n>j) - will it be constant or linear(O(n))?

Or, if I have `p` elements after `Jth` element, then it will be of order `O(p)` -  am I right?

Comment: In fact, it's already said in the link you posted that the complexity is linear.

Comment: So if i have `p` elements after Jth element, then it will be of order O(p), am i right??

Comment: It'll be theta(p)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you provided:

> Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions) plus the number
>   of elements after the last element deleted (moving)

This means that when deleting N=1 elements from the `std::vector`. It will take make N call to the destructor which is equal to 1 in your case. Then it will make M move operation which is equal to `(n-j-1)` in your case. So it is linear not a constant.

So the complixity of std::vector::erase is: `O(Deleted_Items_Count) + O(Moved_Items_Count)`.

In your case: `1*Destructor_Time + (n-j-1)*Moving_Time`

---

In order to erase items from vector in constant time,you may erase them from the tail of the vector(e.g. `std::vector::pop_back`)

So if you want a constant time erasing with no importance of sorting:

```
auto linear_erase=[](auto& v, const size_t index){
    std::swap(v[index], v.back());
    v.pop_back();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Deleting `N` elements from a vector will take a time complexity of `O(N)`, because the application has to iterate over `M` elements, and call each element's destructor, then copy the rest of the elements to the gap created by destroying the erased elements.

So if we have a vector with `N` elements, and we erase the elements from the range `(p,q]` , than destroying the the range will take `O(q-p)` time complexity, which you can say is `O(1)`, because `p` and `q` are constants. then you will have to copy/move the range `(q,N]` . since `N-q` is linear, the time complexity is `O(N)`.

together we get `O(N) + O(1) = O(N)`

of course, if you delete a range that ends in the end of the array, the Complexity is `O(1)` because there are no elements to copy/move.

Answer (score 0):

I learned here on SO that the standard is the best reference.

From [23.3.11.1/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequences#vector.overview-1) [vector.overview]:

> A vector is a sequence container that supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time.

So, in this case `erase` is neither constant nor linear time.
It mostly depends on the kind of operation you are performing:

- It's constant if you are erasing at the end of the vector,
- Otherwise it's linear.